# In a relative layout, how to display the run time textview below another textview?

Tags: java, android

I want to display the hint of each country. When I click the country name it should display the description. For this I have designed the XML with a relative layout with two or more text views (country1,country2) and one text view to be display with description on clicking any country.

The problem is, when I click country 1 the run time text view is not displaying for country 2.

But for country 3 when I click it it is displaying at the bottom. So this means that the text views are not aligning. I get the concept but I'm stuck on how to implement it.

I'm using API version 21

Here's my Java:

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class savev extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    TextView t1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.country);
        t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4);
        t1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.textview1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.textview2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.textview3).setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void toggle_contents(View v,int r,int s){

        /*RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, r);*/
        t1.setVisibility(t1.isShown()? View.GONE: View.VISIBLE);
        t1.setText(s);
        /*t1.setLayoutParams(p);*/
    }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
          switch (v.getId())
          {
          case R.id.textview1:
              toggle_contents(v,R.id.textview1,R.string.country1Meaning);
          break;
          case R.id.textview2:
              toggle_contents(v,R.id.textview2,R.string.country2Meaning);
          break;
          case R.id.textview3:
              toggle_contents(v,R.id.textview3,R.string.country1Meaning);
          break;

          default:break;
          }
     }
}
```

Here's my XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        >
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" 
                android:padding="25dip"
                android:text="country1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="#D8D8D8"
                >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview4"
                android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="12dip"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/customborder"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/customborder"
                android:background="#FF0000"
                >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" 
                android:padding="25dip"
                android:text="country2"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="#D8D8D8"    
                android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"   
                >
        </TextView>
         <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" 
                android:padding="25dip"
                android:text="country3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="#D8D8D8"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textview2"       
                >
        </TextView>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change relative layout to linear

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        >
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" 
                android:padding="25dip"
                android:text="country1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="#D8D8D8"
                >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="12dip"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/customborder"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/customborder"
                android:background="#FF0000"
                >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" 
                android:padding="25dip"
                android:text="country2"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="#D8D8D8"    
                android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"   
                >
        </TextView>
         <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" 
                android:padding="25dip"
                android:visibility="gone
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="#D8D8D8"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textview2"       
                >
        </TextView>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Change description text view position dynamically:

```
    public class savev extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
        TextView txtDesc;
ViewGroup mainContainer; //Linearlayout with textviews
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.country);
            txtDesc=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4);
            mainContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewId(R.id.mainLayout);
            txtDesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.textview1).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.textview2).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.textview3).setOnClickListener(this);
        }




         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) 
         {
              switch (v.getId())
              {
              case R.id.textview1:
                 txtDesc.setText(getString(R.string.country1Meaning));                  
              break;
              case R.id.textview2:
                  txtDesc.setText(getString(R.string.country2Meaning)); 
              break;
              case R.id.textview3:
                  txtDesc.setText(getString(R.string.country3Meaning)); 
              break;

              default:break;
              }
              mainContainer.removeView (txtDesc)
              int pos = mainContainer.indexOfChild(v);
              if(pos>0) {
                   txtDesc.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                   if(pos == getChildCount)
                   mainContainer.addView(txtDesc);
                   else 
                    mainContainer.addView(txtDesc,pos+1);
              }

         }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the value of getchildcount() when you get the error

Comment: Iam not getting the error , the getchildcount value is 3 and i alter the code       if(pos>=0) {
               t1.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
               mainContainer.removeView (t1);
               if(pos == mainContainer.getChildCount()){
                mainContainer.addView(t1,pos);
               }else{
                mainContainer.addView(t1,pos+1);
               }
          } but not working correctly (Click country1 displays description , clicking country 2 it displayed at below text view 3 and text view 3 is working correctly

Comment: Let me debug the findings and post you in few minutes.Right now the behaviour is click on country 1 ->country1 description displayed correctly,click on country 2 the country2 desc displaying at country3 below not at country 2 , click on country 3 working correctly so now pblm is clicking on country2 .I have removed the android:layout_below in the xml since it is linear layout.

Comment: I think I found the issues, add the removeView before getting the position

Comment: Perfect r7v , it works great thank you really.From you now i learnt dynamic text view contents :) .Please tell me the voting options since im new i want to really make your post high vote

Comment: I click right tick mark and im not able to vote since my reputation is low.But cheers